# Bash: detecting key-presses: how to read special key hex sequence(like Insert) and why it is '\x1b\x5b\x32\x7e'(Insert)?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, keyboard, xterm

In the book Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide [Section 5.2 Example 5-3. Detecting key-presses](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html). The whole code can be viewed at [detecting_key-presses.sh](https://gist.github.com/lizhenguo/c910e58a5ad0823f66dce181c47bec7c). In the example, there is some code snippet which I can't understand.

First snippets:

```
# Convert the separate home-key to home-key_num_7:
if [ "$key" = $'\x1b\x4f\x48' ]; then
    key=$'\x1b\x5b\x31\x7e'
    #   Quoted string-expansion construct.
fi

# Convert the separate end-key to end-key_num_1.
if [ "$key" = $'\x1b\x4f\x46' ]; then
    key=$'\x1b\x5b\x34\x7e'
fi

$'\x1b\x5b\x32\x7e')  # Insert
    echo Insert Key
    ;;
```

In the above snippet, for example, when I press <kbd>Home</kbd> key and <kbd>Insert</kbd> key,

1. Why it will produce `\x1b\x4f\x48` sequences for <kbd>Home</kbd> and `\x1b\x5b\x32\x7e` sequences for <kbd>Insert</kbd>?
2. And the comment says that "Convert the separate home-key to home-key_num_7" and "Convert the separate end-key to end-key_num_1", what does the conversion, "key_num_7" and "key_num_1" means?

Second snippet:

```
unset K1 K2 K3
read -s -N1 -p "Press a key: "
K1="$REPLY"
read -s -N2 -t 0.001
K2="$REPLY"
read -s -N1 -t 0.001
K3="$REPLY"
key="$K1$K2$K3"
```

In the above snippet, every time I pressed one key,

1. Why it read 3 variable to construct a key hex sequences?
2. The second `read -s -N2 -t 0.001`, why should specify the `-t`(timeout) option and `-N2`(nchars) to read 2 characters not 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several questions asked...

The script is expecting *escape sequences* to be sent by *special keys*.  On a typical keyboard, those are all of the keys which have a name or graphic symbol (such as ←, for left-cursor).   By *convention* (there is no applicable *standard*) those keys send sequences of characters beginning with <kbd>*escape*</kbd>, with the second character often <kbd>**`[`**</kbd>.  For just those two characters, the hexadecimal codes are *`0x1b`* and *`0x5b`*, respectively (see [ASCII table](http://ascii.cl/)).  The *`0x4f`* is the letter **`O`**, and would be sent by a terminal's special keys in [*application mode*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows).

The particular sequences sent by your <kbd>*Home*</kbd> and <kbd>*End*</kbd> keys use a slightly different convention from some of the other special keys, referred to a *PC-style* (see the xterm FAQ *[Why can't I use the home/end keys?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_pc_style)* for the background on that).  Apparently the developer of the script decided to solve a problem related to that FAQ by ensuring that both variations of the sequences sent by <kbd>*Home*</kbd> and <kbd>*End*</kbd> would be translated into the *VT220-style* sequence.

The last question asks why it is necessary to do separate reads and use separate variables.  That is because the sequence of characters sent by a special key may be transmitted over a network, and take more time than one of those **`read`** operations allows.  So only part of the sequence may be read at each try.  The script collects the pieces and puts them together as one sequence of characters.